# Can't get 2nd player working in Lego SW Force Awakens

Tags: wii-u, lego-star-wars-the-force-awakens

I bought this game for my Wii U a few days ago and I can't seem to figure out how to get a second player working for my kids. I was playing the game with the Wii U gamepad, and have a Wiimote with a Nun-chuck attached. The screen says in the second player area, to "Push + to join", but pushing the plus on the Wiimote is not doing anything, and I can't figure out how to get this working.

I have tried checking in all the menus, and there doesn't seem to be any options to enable it.

I have passed the first Battle of Endor mission in single-player mode.

I have tried syncing the Wiimote.

I have tried searching on the internet.

None of these have solved the issue. Does anyone know what I need to do to get this working? My kids were very disappointed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you got it working yet but you need to have the nunchuck attached. It didn't recognize my controller until I did.

Answer (score -1):

You need a Wiimote and a Nunchuk for the second player to work. The game doesn't give any hint about this.

Comment: This doesn't add anything that wasn't already said by earlier answers.